# IndexMissingException with scala and elastic4s

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

Hello stackoverflowers!

I'm trying to use the library elastic4s with scala, but when I run the following code (in order to fetch the list of ads within the index ads):

```
trait elastic4s {
  def get: Future[SearchResponse] = {
    val client = ElasticClient.local
    client execute { search in "ads"->"ad" }
  }
}
```

I got this exception :

```
An error has occured: org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexMissingException: [ads] missing
```

Pastebin with [full output here.](http://pastebin.com/DgVfZzY4)

Here is my configuration:

```
-- Java
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

-- ElasticSearch
version 1.0.1

-- Elastic4s
version 2.10-1.0.1
```

Elastic Search is up and running, on localhost:9200, and this index ads exists. This CURL request:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/ads/ad/_search'
```

returns

```
{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "ads",
            "_type": "ad",
            "_id": "UrKm89AXTzOxB9kFdpue4Q",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "json": "json"
            }
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

I can't understand... If anyone could give me a track :)

Comment: Have you edited the Elasticsearch configuration? Does your Client maybe have a different Cluster Name?

Comment: Nope MeiSign, Out-of-the-box configuration on both sides (Elastic Search and Elastic4s) :/

Comment: What happens if you use a different query? Maybe a simple Cluster state query or something like that? Or you could try to use "_all" as Index to see if your client can access/see anything.

Comment: I had a look at the Elastic4s lib. Try to use a remote client.
`val client = ElasticClient.remote("localhost", 9300)`
I suspect that your local node client doesnt join your cluster and therefore doesnt find any data...

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions MeiSign. When I use this query code client execute { search in "_all"->"ad" } code - I got this response : code { "took" : 0, "timed_out" : false, "_shards" : { "total" : 0, "successful" : 0, "failed" : 0 }, "hits" : { "total" : 0, "max_score" : 0.0, "hits" : [ ] } } code . The same request executed with CURL returns 5 successful shards. Weird :(

Comment: It's working well when I use a remote client. I'll investigate to know why. Thanks for your help MeiSign :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local node won't communicate with other Elasticsearch instances running outside that process. A local node is local to the JVM.

The code comments say:

> "Is the node a local node. A local node is a node that uses a local
>   (JVM level) discovery  transport. Other (local) nodes started within
>   the same JVM (actually, class-loader) will be discovered and
>   communicated with. Nodes outside of the JVM will not be discovered."

You need to use a remote client to connect to external instances, even if they're running locally. I guess that seems counter-intuitive but remote really means IPC or Socket based.

Comment: Thx for this explanation monkjack. And for your awesome es client !